# Why objective-c's block cannot capture values dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I wanna implement `defer` in objective-c. And here's my code:

```
/**
  RAII : ABC->~ABC
 */
@interface DeferImpl_ : NSObject
/**
 *  init with a callback
 *
 *  @return
 */
-(instancetype) initWithCallback:(void(^)())callback;
/**
 *  a callback
 */
@property(nonatomic, copy) void(^callback)();

@end

/**
 *  Defer
 *
 *  @param X { statement; statement; ... }
 *
 *  @return
 */
#define DEFER(X)  [[DeferImpl_ alloc] initWithCallback:^X]

#define SAFE_INVOKE(x) do{if(x){(x)();}}while(0)
@implementation DeferImpl_
/**
 *  invoke callback
 */
-(void) dealloc {
    SAFE_INVOKE(self.callback);
}

-(instancetype) initWithCallback:(void(^)())callback {
    self = [super init];
    self.callback = callback;
    return self;
}

@end
```

The implementation is simple and seems easy to use.
**But it's buggy!**.

Here comes what I feel frustrated.

```
int main(void)
{
    NSInteger count = 0;
    DEFER({
        NSLog(@"Defer: %@", @(count));
    });
    count = 123;
    NSLog(@"Before defer block!");
    return 0;
}
```

Log is:

> 2017-01-12 17:31:32.401 test[73724:18571479] Defer: 0
>
> 2017-01-12 17:31:32.402 test[73724:18571479] Before defer block!

So is there anyone can tell me why `count` still 0 in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hidden most of your work into macros (not a good programming style!) and your are missing the basic point - `DEFER` calls the block immediately, before even reaching `count = 123`.

If you don't assign the result of `[DeferImpl_ alloc]` to any variable, it will get released *immediately*, also immediately calling the block.

Your current code is the same as writing directly:

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSLog(@"Defer: %@", @(count));
count = 123;
NSLog(@"Before defer block!");
```

If you change your code to:

```
NSInteger count = 0;
id x = DEFER({
    NSLog(@"Defer: %@", @(count));
});
count = 123;
NSLog(@"Before defer block!");
```

Your result will be:

> Before defer block!
>   Defer: 0

Now, why the value is still zero? Because blocks capture variables *by value*. To capture the reference, you will have to add `__block`:

```
__block NSInteger count = 0;
id x = DEFER({
    NSLog(@"Defer: %@", @(count));
});
count = 123;
NSLog(@"Before defer block!");
```

> Before defer block!
>   Defer: 123

See [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6)

Comment: "Note that using __block is a bit dangerous because the block is capturing a piece of local memory and you have to make sure the block is not used once the memory is deallocated" No it isn't. It is safe to use `__block` variables in blocks that capture them even after the function in which they were declared has exited. The memory is usable as long as some block the captures it is still alive.

Comment: @newacct Thanks! I have just learned something new about Obj-C. I always thought `__block` just uses the variable as a memory reference. I never realized the memory is moved completely out of the function stack.